# Top menu bar on mac is being mirrored at the bottom of the screen

Tags: macos, mac

I'm not sure how it happened but when I turned on my mac mini (2018) I noticed that the bottom part of the screen is mirroring the top part. I can't seem to take a screenshot of it either so I just took a picture:

[image]

I tried the usual turning it off and on again and trying around the monitor's setting but to no avail. Any ideas how it happened and how can I solve this?

Comment: If you can't get a screenshot of it, that points to it being the display hardware. Try setting the display to different resolutions & see what happens.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah I see it even on the apple boot screen so it must be the monitor. The monitor doesn't allow me to change the resolution though.

Comment: Really, then, the only options are try a different cable [or if available, different connection method, DVI/HDMI/VGA etc], or try a different display.